# TLS handshake fail, but communication is not closed

Tags: ssl, tcp, wireshark, tls1.2, telnet

I have TLS program and I did some experiments on it.

I start confidential TLS server session and try to connect to it with pure Telnet client.

As expected, the handshake failed and the server is available to the next client but on the Telnet client side I didn't receive any indication that the handshake failed and that the server is accepting other clients.
I can see in Wireshark that even after the handshake failed the Telnet client can send strings; I see [PSH, ACK] from the client answered by [ACK] from the server.

Adding Wireshark snapshot, Telnet failed the handshake, Telnet keep sending messages, followed by success in the TLS handshake and more Telnet messages:

[image: wireshark snap]

Why is the server ACKing the Telnet client if the handshake failed and he is accepting other clients?

Comment: "I didn't received any indication that ... the server is accepting other clients": you never will. Can't imagine what you were expecting here.

Comment: Most of this is false. (1) This is not a 'pure Telnet client'; it is speaking TLS. (2) The Telnet client received a TLS alert, which is an 'indication that the handshake failed'. (3) There is no such thing as 'an indication that the server is [or isn't] accepting other clients'. (4) The Telnet client then received a FIN. (4) the Telnet client received an RST. After this the connection ceases to exist. I can't account for what follows: is it really part of the same stream? There is a rather suspicious 3-second gap at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As expected, the handshake failed ...

I cannot see a failed TLS handshake in the packet capture and I'm not sure how you come to this conclusion.

All I can see that the client on source port 60198 (presumable your telnet) is sending 3 bytes several times and the server just ACK'ing these without sending anything back and without closing the connection. Likely the server is still expecting data in the hope that at some time it will be a complete TLS record. Only then it will be processed by the TLS stack and then it might realize that something is wrong with the client.

> ... the server is available to the next client

It is pretty normal for a server to handle multiple clients in parallel. In contrary, it would be unusual if the server could not do this.

Comment: Thanks @steffen, It is normal for the server to handle multiple clients, but I expected the server to close communication after handshake failed.

Comment: @lior.i: *"... but I expected the server to close communication after handshake failed"* - but the handshake did not fail (yet). The server was still waiting for the ClientHello to get completed. That's why the server did not close the connection.